# Comparing a string to a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, comparison

I have some weird js-source here, that comapres a string to a **twodimensional** array:

```
secret = new Array(2);
secret[0]= new Array(2);
secret[1]= new Array(2);

secret[0][0] = 'A';
secret[0][1] = 'B';
secret[1][0] = 'C';
secret[1][1] = 'D';

pwd=prompt("Password: ","");
if (pwd==secret){
alert("Right!");
}
else{
alert("Wrong!");
}
```

How does js do that comparison? Is the array converted to a string or the other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is implicitly converted to a string, `"A,B,C,D"`.